# Do I need to close the OS-level handle returned to me by tempfile.mkstemp if not using it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a temporary file to write some data out to in Python 3. The file will be written to via a separate module which deals with opening the file from a path given as a string.

I'm using `tempfile.mkstemp()` to create this temporary file and according to the docs:

> `mkstemp()` returns a tuple containing an OS-level handle to an open file (as would be returned by `os.open()`) and the absolute pathname of that file, in that order.

Given I'm not going to be using the open OS-level file handle given to me, do I need to close it? I understand about regular Python file handles and closing them but I'm not familiar with OS-level file descriptors/handles.

So is this better:

```
fd, filename = tempfile.mkstemp()
os.close(fd)
```

Or can I simply just do this:

```
_, output_filename = tempfile.mkstemp()
```

Comment: I think you are being confused by the term "OS-level handle". As stated in the quote you attached, this handle is **the same** as would be returned from calling `open()`, so you should treat it exactly the same as a regular file. So, yes, close it. You don't have much to do with the filename. it is just a string. The reason it is returned as well, is because it is a temp file and given an arbitrary name

Comment: @Tomerikoo I don't believe that's true. `os.open()` and `open()` are two quite different functions and return two very different things. `os.open` docs say ". Return the file descriptor for the newly opened file." whereas the `open()` docs say "Open file and return a corresponding file object.". So one returns a number, a OS-level file descriptor, and one returns a Python file object.

Comment: This answer could help you with your task. There is some useful info about `tempfile` module. https://stackoverflow.com/a/20912974/841339

Comment: @JamieScott sorry for that, I was the one confused... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The returned file descriptor is not a file object, the garbage collector will not close it for you.
You should use:

```
fd, filename = tempfile.mkstemp()
os.close(fd)
```

The returned file descriptor is useful to avoid race conditions where the filename is replaced with a symbolic link to a file that the attacker can not read but you can which can result in data exposure.