# Python class containing a temporary file

Tags: python

I would like to create a Python class which contains a temporary file.

If I use the usual `tempfile.TemporaryFile()` with a context manager to create a member variable in the constructor, then the context manager will close/delete the temporary file when the constructor exits. This is no good because I want the file to exist for the lifetime of the class.

I see that I could create my own [context managed class](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html#implementing-a-context-manager-as-a-class) using `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods, does anyone have any examples of this? (Maybe I just need to add a line to delete the file to the example in the link?)

Or maybe there's a better way of doing this?

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20912896/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-close-a-python-temporary-file-returned-by-mkstem) help at all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explaining Python's '\_\_enter\_\_' and '\_\_exit\_\_'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984325/explaining-pythons-enter-and-exit)

Comment: @quamrana, that link does not mention classes

Comment: @Homer512, Not really. It matches the link in my post. I know how to create a context managed class, but I'm looking for an implementation which manages a temporary file. Do I just need to add a line to delete the file, as I said in my post?

Comment: The first answer to the linked question is a class managing a ```dbconn``` handle and the ```__exit__``` method calls ```self.dbconn.close()```. Guess what method you would call on a ```tempfile.TemporaryFile``` handle?

Comment: Does it have to mention classes? You are only wanting the temporary file to last while the constructor is running.

Comment: Yes. I need to create a class which uses a temporary file as part of its implementation. So I need the file to last for the lifetime of the class.

Comment: So not: `"close/delete the temporary file when the constructor exits."`?

Comment: No. I was saying that *if* I used a context managed temporary file in the constructor, then it would be deleted when the constructor exits. I want the temporary file to exist for the lifecycle of the whole class.

Comment: Ok, I see. Perhaps just keep the file in a member variable and rely on reference counting to close the file when the instance is garbage collected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following

```
class TemporaryFile:
  def __init__(self, *, data: str):
      self._data = data

  def __enter__(self):
      self._file = NamedTemporaryFile()
      self._file.write(data)
      self._file.flush()
      return self

  def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb):
      self._file.close()

  def sample_method():
      pass
```

Which is used like so:

```
with TemporaryFile(data=data) as file:
   file.sample_method()
```